# how to assign a number by two column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to assign a number by two column, If the two columns are interleaved and equal, then need to get the same number.
please see the picture.
Because of the huge amount of data, I don't want to use loops, can anyone help me?thanks a lot!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vybPX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-row_number/) in this case

```
SELECT row_number() over (partition by key1, key2 order by key1, key2) AS rn FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).